# how to use red * symbol on top of textview in android

Tags: java, android, textview

I have a text view. Text view is mandatory so I want `*` symbol on top of text view in red color.[image]

Comment: use some image inside imageview right of textView whose gravity is top|left

Comment: use * with html.fromhtml();

Comment: Or use `SpannableString`

Answer (score 8):

```
TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
String simple = "Enter your name ";
String colored = "*";
SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder(simple+colored);

builder.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), simple.lenth(), builder.length(), 
            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

text.setText(builder);
```

Answer (score 6):

One of the easiest way to achieve this by using following code in your strings.xml file and provide color in your color.xml file

```
<string name="user_name">UserName <font color='red'>*</font></string>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    TextView txt_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    String simple = "Name";
    String colored = "*";

    SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
    builder.append(simple);
    int start = builder.length();
    builder.append(colored);
    int end = builder.length();

    builder.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), start, end, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    txt_name.setText(builder);
```

Comment: it is working but it is not coming on top i want small icon in top locking like in picture

Comment: Hey sourabhjain, why are u used icon for asterisk sign? is there any reason of that ?

Comment: no i want just * top end now its coming after text as red color loking like red text  i want  half size * after text see in image

Comment: <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="name" />

Answer (score 0):

You can use unicode for ["ASTERISK"](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2a/index.htm) for that, this is upper version of "*", and use method above with spannable string.